# WSO2-AM 3.2.0 - Developer Portal - redirecting to localhost

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to access WSO2 Developer Portal sing-in page on a docker environment but I'm been automatically redirected to localhost.

I access Developer Portal using this address:

```
https://192.168.21.120:9443/devportal/apis
```

When I click in Sign-In button I'm redirected to:

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&c...
```

Where can I fixe this url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the following configuration in the `deployment.toml`

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
```

You will also have to update the SP as per below doc.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/#

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in a docker container .

Pick the container. We need id from it.

```
docker ps -a
```

open the container kernel containerid is actual id

```
docker exec -u 0 -it containerid /bin/bash
```

find folders in the container and use the api manager one below

```
ll
```

find where your deployment.toml is in the apimanager folder

```
find wso2amfolder/ -type f -name deployment.toml
```

open your file with terminal editor

```
 nano routetofile/deployment.toml
```

Not actual values but references

1. routetofile
2. wso2amfolder
3. containerid